# Inserting data while iterating over a result set using prepared statments

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm starting to use the MySQL prepare and I have a problem.
How do `SELECT` and `INSERT` then?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","pass","db");

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT url FROM servers");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($data);

$query2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO links(url) VALUES (?)");
$query2->bind_param("s", $data);   

while ($query->fetch())
{
  echo $data;
  $query2->execute();
  $query2->close();
}
$query->close();
```

I tested this code and error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `bind_param()` on a non-object in ...

Where is problem?

Comment: You got any errors ?  Have you assigned values to `$data` and `$data2` ?

Comment: No, select is OK, but insert does not work. (not insert data to database)

Comment: 'Does not work' is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: $data and $data are data from DB (from select)

Comment: Can you able to echo the `$data` and `$data2` and check the datatype that you use to insert in the coloumn `x,x2` ?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to see what is the error returned by MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible problems.

#### Two open statements at the same time

I ran into this problem I few times myself. If you want to use nested mysqli statements, you have to "finish" the database call before making another database call.

In your context: PHP haven't finished the first call with `$query->execute();`. If you now run `$query->fetch()`, a single row is fetched from the database and the statement blocks the connection, since the statement is not closed.

If you want to use another statement, you have to close this by using `$query->close()` (this does not work in your case) or by using `$query->store_result()` (this is what you want). [`mysqli::store_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) transfers the whole result set from the database into the memory and frees the connection for the next query.

#### Multiple closing of `$query2`

In your `while` loop, you close the query `$query2` in every iteration, so `$query2->execute()` cannot be executed after the first iteration. This line should be moved out of the loop.

*Notice*: I have not tested anything of this. This are only problems I know about and I think the might be also the problem in your case.

I hope this helps.

#### Possible improvement

Maybe you can use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`-Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) to improve the performance.
This also would remove the nested statements. You can first select and print all data and after this you can run a `INSERT ... SELECT` query to copy all data in the other table (or the other way around).

Comment: @HonzaSynek you're welcome. I added a possible improvement to my answer.